# If image size javascript condition is ok show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I need some help. I'm trying to make a condition in javascript to show a div after and object is resized and have the width and height i need to.

This is my code

HTML

```
<img id="image1" src="img/object1" width="107" height="30">
<img id="image2" src="img/onject1" width="107" height="240">
```

Javascript

```
$("#image2").hide();
$( "#image1" ).resizable({ maxHeight: 240 , maxWidth : 107 , minWidth: 107});
```

So i need somethimg like this

```
$('#image1').click(function(){

if $('#image1') have height 240 and width 107
show $('#image2')

);
```

But i don't know how to write this condition. Please help me.

Is there any possibility to auto show image2 when image1 is resized to height 240 and width 107 ?

Thanks

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($('#image1').width() == 107 && $('#image1').height() == 240){
  $('#image2').show()
}
```

if use want to auto show that in resizing event use [event-resize](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-resize)

```
$( "#image1" ).resizable({ 
     maxHeight: 240 , 
     maxWidth : 107 , 
     minWidth: 107,
     resize: function (event, ui){
      if($('#image1').width() == 107 && $('#image1').height() == 240){
        $('#image2').show()
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The condition would be:

```
if ($('#image1').height() == 240 && $('#image1').width() == 107) {

    $('#image2').show();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

hope it will help you

```
$('#image1').on('click',function(){

   if($('#image1').width() == 107 && $('#image1').height() == 240) {

      $('#image2').show()
   }

);
```